# Re-asking a question that was put on hold, never re-reviewed and subsequently closed

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions, etiquette

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42729880/generating-a-directed-graph-with-rigid-structure-on-subgraphs-in-python) was put on hold for something of a technicality.

I edited the question to comply with the off-topic rules and had hoped that the question would be re-opened; but it seems nobody has reviewed it and it has subsequently closed.

If I re-submit the question as it now is, will it be placed on hold or closed for either:

1. Being a duplicate of a previously submitted post (I suspect this would happen automatically), or
2. Any other reason?

I am happy to re-post the question as, even if it were re-opened, I fear it would not get any visibility at this stage: really, I would just like my question to be given a fair shot at being answered now that (I think) it complies with site rules.

Comment: FYI: Your post did go through the reopen vote queue and it was unanimously marked as leave closed: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/15491383

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find this out but I don't think I was able to due to being a new user.

Comment: You can find it in the post timeline.  SO doesn't provide a link to it but you can get there using `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/<post-id>/timeline`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was [rereviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/15491383) all the reviewers voted for the question to remain closed.

There's no reason to think that posting the same question yet again would achieve a different result so you need to figure out what's still wrong with the existing question and address those failings.

At the moment it's not really a programming question. If you want to make it one, include the graphviz code you've written as a [Minimal Complete and  Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Ideally you'd show that you've tried various things to get the effect that you wanted but that they didn't achieve it. Screenshots of what you've got so far and what you want (that you could create using a raster graphics editor) might help too.

Asking for other alternatives to graphviz is going to make it subject to closure as an off-topic tool request.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand that asking for alternatives to graphviz is going to get it re-closed as off-topic. I am finding the subtle differences between this and say, a question like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940128/how-can-i-reverse-a-list-in-python that asks a similarly generic question hard to grasp. In both cases, the asker would like to make python do something (reverse a list vs plot a graph with added structure forced on vertices); in both instances, the expected solution is of the form 'use this function' - the only difference I can see is that the solution (cont.)

Comment: to my question most likely requires use of another library or a function in graphviz that I am not sure exists. How does this make it less of a programming question?

Comment: Figure out what library you want first. We're not going to do that for you. Once you've found one and tried it and got stuck, that's the point to ask a question.

Comment: Also comparing what you can ask now with what you could ask 7 years ago when the site was in it's infancy and the rules were different is not going to help you.

Comment: The easiest question I could think of that would be answered on this site was 'sorting a list'; I picked the first google result as a concrete example. I would like my question to be answered; as such I need my question to stay open; as such I clearly need to understand exactly why it is closed. My previous comments are asking, politely, for clarification on this matter because I don't understand things that are 'unwritten rules'. Please don't interpret them as trying to 'argue' with you; I'm under no illusion that that would be an unproductive path to go down.

Comment: In reply to your other comment: does trying to do it with graphviz and not being able to find a function to do this count as figuring out which library I want, and subsequently getting stuck? I genuinely do not understand what more I can do in this regard.

Comment: OK you've decided graphviz is the library, update your question about it and don't confuse things by asking about any other library. Follow the advice I've already given you in the answer to improve your question.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Do I need to update the pre-existing question or should I re-write it and submit it as a new question? If it's subsequently re-opened, will it stay buried as having been asked last weekend?

Comment: If it's too similar to the existing question you run the risk of it simply being closed as a duplicate of that so I'd go with editing, if you do that you might attract reopen votes simply as a result of this meta question.

Comment: Done. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @TomH You missed the crucial part of Robert's advice: edit your question to include a MCVE.

Comment: @Louis: This seems a bit daft in this instance as all I can make graphviz do is plot the graph, which is the most basic functionality of graphviz - but okay, I'll add that as well.

Comment: @TomH there are plenty of examples where something you'd expect to be "the most basic functionality" is the core of the question... Something like "why my `if` statement does not run when condition is false" is not too far from some questions I've seen. So showing what you already know is important part of the question (and MCVE is an easy way to do so). And https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Common_sense_is_not_common :)

Comment: Ha, okay, thanks. I've now updated it with a MCVE that I think does the job.